# acts_as_list how to add a second list based on related table column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-list

In a Rails 3.2 app I'm trying to add an acts_as_list to the model `costproject`.

Client model:

```
belongs_to :department
```

Costproject model:

```
belongs_to :client
```

Both `department_priority` is in `Costproject`.

It needs to be based on `costproject.client.department_id'

This is what I've tried:

```
  acts_as_list :column => :department_priority, :scope => 'client.department_id'
  acts_as_list :column => :department_priority, :scope => [client.department_id]
  acts_as_list :column => :department_priority, :scope => [costproject.client.department_id]
```

What should the scope be to make this work? It acts like I need an inner join?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you give more details about the models involved (client, department, priority?) and their relations?